# Why is the voltage across the resistor R zero during the negative half cycle for a clipper circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2rX7z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

During the positive half cycle the output voltage is 4V when it is forward biased and Vinput = Voutput when it is reverse biased. I can relate to that.

I don't understand why my source says the voltage across R1 is 0 during the negative half cycle.

[image]

Comment: Here's a hint: In order to have a voltage across a resistor, there must be current flowing through it. What happens to the diode during the negative half cycle of your 8V sine wave?

Comment: During the negative cycle, is the diode on or off? During negative cycle, is there current flowing in the circuit?

Comment: Visually No. The current is not flowing. However, if there is no current how come will there be voltage as Voltage is related to the current that flows through the circuit?

Comment: @DerStrom8 Freshman year. My deep apologies for being unable to leverage your hints.

Comment: Voltage is **not necessarily** "related to the current". For a resistor this is certainly true, but a large voltage can exist across an open circuit when no current flows.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson All of my life have been thinking the other way around until now. This is so enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Real circuit.** The diode D and 4 V voltage source are shown on the schematic but they do nothing during the "negative half cycle". More precisely speaking, the total resistance of the two elements in series is much larger than the resistance R1. A voltage divider with a transfer ratio of about 1 is formed.

[image: Real circuit]

**2. Circuit with "redundant" elements removed.** So we can remove (erase) the redundant elements from the schematic.

[image: Circuit with redundant elements removed]

**3. Circuit with zeroed resistance.** Also, the resistor R1 does nothing during the "negative half cycle"; it behaves like a piece of wire so we can replace it by a piece of wire on the schematic. More precisely speaking, the resistance R1 is much less than the load resistance (not shown in the diagram). A voltage divider with a transfer ratio of about 1 is formed.

[image: Circuit with zeroed resistance]

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to see things if you redraw the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyRcFg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$D_1\$ is ideal and will only conduct when \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\ge +4\:\text{V}\$.

So when the \$V_1=8\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$ source is below \$+4 \:\text{V}\$ diode \$D_1\$ is **off**. Since nothing else is connected to \$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$, there cannot be any current in \$R_1\$. So no voltage drop across it. So when the \$8\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$ source is below \$+4 \:\text{V}\$ then \$V_{_\text{OUT}}=V_1\$. The output just follows the source voltage.

But when the \$V_1=8\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$ source is at or above \$+4 \:\text{V}\$ diode \$D_1\$ is **on** and this fact forces \$V_{_\text{OUT}}=+4 \:\text{V}\$. It cannot change at all, even as \$V_1\$ changes, so long as \$V_1\ge +4\:\text{V}\$, as the diode is ideal and has no voltage drop across it. So the anode must be at the same voltage as the cathode.

So you would expect the curves you show.

However, you also write:

> I don't understand why my source says the voltage across R1 is 0
> during the negative half cycle.

That English phrasing does have a problem. The voltage across \$R_1\$ is \$0\:\text{V}\$ while \$V_1\lt +4\:\text{V}\$ and ***not*** while \$V_1\lt 0\:\text{V}\$. So the *half-cycle* phrasing is wrong. The voltage across \$R_1\$ is \$0\:\text{V}\$ for **more** than a half-cycle. The intersection of a \$+4\:\text{V}\$ line and the \$8\:\text{V}_\text{AC}\$ sine occurs at \$\frac{\pi}6\$ and \$5\frac{\pi}6\$, so this means that it occurs for a period of \$360^\circ-120^\circ=240^\circ\$. Which is decidedly ***not*** \$180^\circ\$, as suggested.